# How to rebind controller in spine.js?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, spine.js

How to rebind controller when it was initializated before element (this.el) was in DOM?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution. You need to add new method to Spine controller. This method is mostly the same as Controller.replace but without replacing DOM elements.

```
Spine.Controller.prototype.rebind = function(element) {
    var previous, _ref;
    _ref = [this.el, $(element.el || element)], previous = _ref[0], this.el = _ref[1];
    this.delegateEvents(this.events);
    this.refreshElements();
    return this.el;
};
```